# How to bindkey alt+delete to kill word forward in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, key-binding, oh-my-zsh

I want to bindkey alt+delete to kill word forward in zsh. Also, I use ohmyzsh for configuration, and I have found that use "bindkey ^U backward-kill-line" to kill line backward like bash. I want to use "bindkey <alt+delete> backward-kill-word", but I don't know the escape code for alt+delete.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I found the answer, it should be `bindkey '^[[3;3~' kill-word` .